# parse specific json string on wp8 app

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I'm creating wp8 application and have to parse specific json string:

```
string jsonStr = {
    "ver": "1",
    "item1": {
        "name": "name1",
        "desc": "desc1"
    },
    "item2": {
        "name": "name2",
        "desc": "desc2"
    },
    "item3": {
        "name": "name3",
        "desc": "desc3"
    }
}
```

I need values of key name to get in list, eg. name1, name2, name3. I was trying to find similar situation but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but I think there will be more elegant way to solve this problem. However you can use it.

```
var jsonStr = "{\"ver\":\"1\",\"item1\":{\"name\":\"name1\",\"desc\":\"desc1\"},\"item2\":{\"name\":\"name2\",\"desc\":\"desc2\"},\"item3\":{\"name\":\"name3\",\"desc\":\"desc3\"}}";

List<string> names = new List<string>();

JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
jsonObject.Remove("ver");

foreach (JToken jsonRow in jsonObject.Children())
{
    foreach (JToken item in jsonRow)
    {
        foreach (JToken itemProperty in item)
        {
            var property = itemProperty as JProperty;
            if (property != null && property.Name == "name")
            {
                if (property.Value != null)
                {
                    names.Add(property.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is elegant enough for me. Probably we could define classes according to objects first and use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject but this is great solution.